# Switch between fullscreen apps, wrap around?

Tags: macos, trackpad

I have multiple full screen applications running on my Mac. I use three finger swipe to scroll through them. When they are in order I have to move from app 1 to app n by swiping n times. Is there a way to wrap them around so that when i swipe beyond app n, I can reach app 1?

Answer (score 1):

No but you can use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> if you want a wraparound. Another thing you can do is this:

Swipe up with three fingers. You’ll see every window that is opened right now. If it isn’t fullscreen it will be somewhere in the middle of your screen. If it is in Fullscreen it will be on top next to the desktop window. You can order them by holding one and then moving it to the position you want.

For instance you have Safari, Pages and Calender opened and you want Pages to be the first fullscreen after swiping with three fingers from the desktop. You only have to swipe with three fingers up and drag the Safari fullscreen right next to desktop.

[image: thats what it looks like if you swipe up]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to perform such wrap around. However, there's an easier way to overcome the problem of swiping left or right **n** number of times.

You can enable Mission Control gesture for your Trackpad and easily swipe up to reveal all the running full screen apps and Spaces. Then it's possible to easily click to jump to desired full screen app or Space.

[image]

It is also possible to rearrange individual Spaces and full screen apps by dragging and dropping. You can even move them between monitors if you use a multi screen setup.